# Rails 3: mysql query adjustment

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jquery_token_input after following Ryan Bates railscast #258 and this is the code in the authors controller that searchs the entered query and produces json to render the autocomplete list. 
Currently it selects the authors where the name is like the params entered.

### Authors controller

```
def index
  @authors = Author.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @authors.map(&:attributes) }
  end
end
```

The author model has the columns :name and :user_id. I'd like to first select authors where the user_id is equal to the current_user.id. And then to select from that array the authors whos name is like the params entered.

Does this make sense? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being the line I needed: (I have a helper method called uid)

```
def index
 @authors = Author.where(:user_id => uid).where(["name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%"])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @authors.map(&:attributes) }
  end
end
```

Is there a way to improve this by removing the second where? Does that even matter?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to first select authors where
>   the user_id is equal to the
>   current_user.id.

Sounds strange. Assuming user_id is the primary key this should return exactly one result (or none); but never a list of authors.

Comment: The user_id column on the author model separate authors by the user's who created them. I'd like the current_user's id to be used to select authors, therefore showing all authors created by the current_user.